# Copy cells if value is higher than another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell (**U4**, for example) where I insert a value. I'll call it A, for example.

I want to copy all the values in Column K higher than A (starting in row 4), and place them in Column N (starting in row 4 also). Besides that, i want to copy the correspondent values in Column L and place them in column O.

Right now I have this, just for Column K:

```
A = Range("U4").Value
Cotacopy = 4
With Range("K4")
If .Cells(1, 1).Value > A Then
      Range(.Cells(1, 1), .End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Cálculo").Range("N" & Cotacopy)
    x = x + 1
Else
End If
End With
```

I don't know if this is entirely correct, i'm adapting another process where i copy all the cells in one column that have value.

Comment: What happens if K is lower than A? and do you always want the value in column L to placed in column O regardless of whether the value in K is smaller or larger in A?

Comment: If K is lower than A, i want it to skip the value. It doesn't matter. I'm only focused on values higher than A. 
About the second part, no. I just want to copy the values from column L that correspond to values in K higher than A.

Comment: Ok, just updated my code to include that. Let me know if you have any questions about the loop.

Comment: i don't know what i'm doing wrong, but it is copying all the column K and L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following **For loop**:

```
Sub CopyHigherValue()

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

y = 4

For x = 4 To lastrow
    If Cells(x, 1).Value < Cells(x, 11).Value Then
          Cells(y, 14).Value = Cells(x, 11).Value
          Cells(y, 15).Value = Cells(x, 12).Value
          y = y + 1
    End If
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I changed it and i got it working. But it places the values in column N and O, in the same row as they were. And i want them to move up (to row 4, columns N and O)

Comment: Updated the code to start adding the values from row 4.

Comment: i think that was not exactly my condition, but it's working right now. changed the if condition to  If Cells(x, 11).Value >= A Then